# Can Neutron Activation Analysis differ isotopes?

Tags: radiation, research-level, neutrons

I know to carry out an NAA analysis, the specimen is placed into a suitable irradiation facility and bombarded with neutrons. This creates artificial radioisotopes of the elements present. Following irradiation, the artificial radioisotopes decay with emission of particles or, more importantly gamma rays, which are characteristic of the element from which they were emitted. But we can not only difffer elements, but also the isotopes of the same element using this technique?

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each nucleus has a specific set of internal energy levels. If you add a neutron to one nucleus, you will now have a different isotope with different internal energy levels, so it will emit a different spectrum of gamma rays. The internal energy levels and gamma rays (and intensities of each energy) emitted from different nuclear reactions are tabulated at the Evaluated Nuclear Data Structure File databases. I tend to use the location at [Brookhaven](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/), you may have a faster connection to one of the other mirrors.

What to do:
Go to ENSDF

Search for  U-236

Select the '235U(N,G) E=THERMAL' entry, and ask for the pdf

You will get an 8 page document. The first page shows the known internal energy levels for U-236. Pages 2 through 6 list all the various gamma energies known for U-236, the intensities for the particular reaction selected, and a bunch of other information. Pages 7 and 8 show those gamma energies in a level scheme so you can see which transitions result in which energy gammas.

Now, go search for U-239, and look at the '238U(N,G) E=THERMAL' entry. Now you get all that same info, but for the U-239 nucleus. And it is a 12 page pdf now, and all the energy levels and gamma intensities are different.

So, yes, using neutron activation analysis you can determine isotopes.

Answer (score -1):

NAA is a strong analytical method for identifying and quantifying trace elements and isotopes in a variety of materials, including biological, geological, and environmental samples. The approach works by hitting a sample with neutrons, which produces short-lived isotopes that decay by emitting distinctive gamma rays.

It is feasible to identify the elements and isotopes present in the sample and establish their concentrations by analyzing the gamma-ray spectra generated by the decay of these isotopes. This is because various isotopes release gamma rays with varying energy when they decay, allowing for distinction and measurement.

NAA has the benefit of being a non-destructive technology, which implies that the sample may be reused.

Comment: Have you ever worked with this technique to be sure?